# Как в nuxt 3 перенести данные между страницами

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как перенести данные между страницами (pages) в nuxt3. Пробовал использовать как vuex, как pinia, как и  встроенный useState. SSR включен. Использую `<script setup></script>`

Comment: откуда куда, как сделан переход?